# How can I capture the name of a C# static string resource property without changing the caller?

Tags: c#

Having string resources in Strings.resx/Strings.Designer.cs, used like this:

```
myObject.DoSomething(Strings.HelloWorld);
```

can I capture the resource id (i.e. "Strings.HelloWorld") in DoSomething without changing the source line that calls DoSomething? I want the name of the static property defined in Strings.Designer.cs, along with the string value.

What I've figured out is:

```
myObject.DoSomething(() => Strings.HelloWorld);
```

and then:

```
void DoSomething(Expression<Func<string>> expr)
{
    string id = expr.Body.ToString();
    string value = (expr.Compile())();
    // do something with these...
}
```

That changes the original line slightly, but it's still readable and the compiler is checking the property name for me.

**I was wondering if there is any C# magic to do this without changing that original line.**

EDIT: Really, I just want unique ints for each string resource that I use to format a TraceEvent message, to use as the TraceEvent id. I don't want to maintain a list of ints myself when the compiler can do that for me, adding one every time I insert a new source line to trace something else interesting. I get my ints once in initialization by mapping the ResourceSet keys to a sequence of ints, and I don't mind if the numbers shift around from build to build.

EDIT2: Referring to LBushkin's answer, I did initially map strings to int, like this:

```
var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

var sorted =
    from i in resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    orderby i.Key
    select i.Value as string;

var valueToId = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (string value in sorted)
{
    valueToId[value] = valueToId.Count + 100; // whatever range you like
}
```

...but I don't like relying on a static CurrentCulture. I want a simple low-tech, low-maintenance mapping of the resource strings to unique ints, where all I need to do is add strings in the designer when I feel like it.

Comment: why do you need this , can you provide idea what are you going to do with it ?

Comment: I'm as interested in @vittore. It seems like that if you are going to do that then a custom implementation would suit you better than the built-in functionality.

Comment: @vittore, @Ritch Melton: It's a low-tech way to get unique ids for TraceEvent calls based on the format string used to format the message. From ResourceManager.GetResourceSet I make a dictionary of string ids to ints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there isn't anything that will do this. The lambda expression is the closest you'll get.

EDIT: **Warning - smelly code ahead**

At least, that's the case if you don't want to add extra methods in another Strings class in the same namespace as the caller. Here's a really grotty hack:

```
// You'd want to autogenerate this class based on the designer file.
public class Strings
{
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return global::OriginalNS.Strings.HelloWorld;
    }
}
```

then...

```
void DoSomething(Func<string> provider)
{
    string id = provider.Method.Name;
    string value = provider();
}
```

Now this:

```
myObject.DoSomething(Strings.HelloWorld);
```

is compiled into a method group conversion using the *method* `Strings.HelloWorld`. `DoSomething` finds the name of that method to get the ID, and calls the delegate to get the actual value.

This will only work if `Strings` is in a different namespace to the method calling `DoSomething`, so that you can hijack the use of the name `Strings`. I suppose another alternative would be a using directive:

```
using Strings = EvilStrings;
```

In general though: urgh! Don't do this! It's fun to think about, of course, but I wouldn't wish it on production code...

Comment: Ohh. Deliciously evil. I love it. Although I’d have to flagellate myself after using it.

Comment: @Konrad: Does that count as an added bonus? ;)

Comment: I don't want to touch the designer file if I can help it. I'd rather change the DoSomething(string str) to DoSomething(Expression<Func<string>> expr) once and fix the compile errors, and then live with the new lambda expression syntax, which is not too bad to look at. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Jim: This wouldn't be *changing* the designer file... it would be generating *another* file. But I still wouldn't suggest you do it :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I got that. Don't worry, I won't do this, although, I do like the class name "EvilStrings".

Comment: I think the original solution from Jim is better, less smelly.

Comment: @Vince: Yes, other than it not accomplishing the aim of avoiding code changes for the caller. That's the only reason I went down this path :)

Comment: While a creative (and evil) apprach, the OP's approach seems like the wrong way to address the actual problem. I've posted an alternative answer that may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your intent, it seems like you're making things more complicated than they really need to be.**

While Jon's solution is certainly creative, I would approach this much more practically.

If all you're trying to do is associate each string resource with a unique number that you can retrieve in various places, then I suggest that you write a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) catalog to do this. The catalog would essentially be a dictionary mapping strings to unique values. Alternatively, you could use the name of the string resource property as the id, rather than a number. Either way, you could use reflection to build this on startup:

```
public static class StringCatalog
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string,int> m_CatalogMap;

    static StringCatalog()
    {
        m_CatalogMap = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        // use reflection to discover and assign unique IDs to string resources
        // ... LEFT AS AN EXCERCISE ...
    }

    public static int GetId( string stringResource )
    {
        return m_CatalogMap[stringResource];
    }
}
```

Your consumers would then look something like:

```
void DoSomething(string s)
{    
    int id = StringCatalog.GetId(s);

    // use the string as you would normally...
}
```

Comment: This will only work if each ID maps to a unique string. You could easily end up with two properties (Strings.Foo and Strings.Bar) which result in the same string, at least for some cultures. At that point, there's no way of telling which ID was used to retrieve the string.

Comment: @Jon: You are correct, in principle. However, based on the OPs described use case, it would seem strange to have two different IDs for what (to users) apears as the same text. Also, if perfect fidelity is truly necessary, it's possible to prefix (or suffix) each string with a uniquifier that is removed by the `StringCatalog` on demand (at the cost of extra memory use). Since I think a diversity of approaches has educational merit, I will leave my answer for posterity.

Comment: In my experience it's quite usual for two IDs to have the same translation in *some* cultures, but be maintained because the two contexts may have different translations in *other* cultures.

Comment: My initial implementation mapped strings to ints (see edit in question) but I don't like depending on a static CurrentCulture. I don't want prefixes in the string because that defeats the idea of a low-tech solution that just works without any maintenance.